# Is Django model ordering also an indexing?

Tags: django, postgresql

Per the Django docs, ordering is "The default ordering for the object, for use when obtaining lists of objects". This is great, but I don't see anything about indexing the database with this ordering.

Does Django add an index with this ordering as well? Or should I add `indexes` under `ordering` as well? That just seems redundant though.

Comment: No, it simply will each time add a `.order_by(..)` clause if no other `.order_by(..)` in the queryset is present.

Comment: Do you know if it orders the actual data in the DB making an indexing not necessary? Or should I definitely add one for efficiency purposes?

Comment: an index is only useful in a database context. It performs the ordering in the database.

Comment: Although Django doesn't implicitly add an index for the default ordering of a model, adding an index manually may help to improve ordering performance. Also, to quote the Zen of Python,
"Explicit is better than implicit."